# mix default interface with two additional interfaces

Tags: typescript

I just want to extend an "Error interface" with two additional options.

typescript playground: https://tsplay.dev/Nr5Mlw

1. `interface Error` is an common interface describing default Error
2. `interface RequestError` and `interface InvariantError` just extending common interface

issue: the Response Error interface has to be a mix of that three interfaces

```
interface Error {
  error: {
    message?: string,
    name: "InvariantError" | "RequestError" | string,
  };
}

interface InvariantError extends Error {
  error: {
    message: string,
    name: "InvariantError",
  };
}

interface RequestError extends Error {
  error: {
    name: "RequestError",
    response: {
      message?: string,
    },
  };
}

type ResponseError = Error & (InvariantError | RequestError);

const { error }: ResponseError = { error: { message: "Test", name: "Error" } };

if (error.name === "InvariantError") {
  console.log(error.message);
} else if (error.name === "RequestError") {
  console.log(error.response.message);
} else {
  console.log(error.message); // <-- The issue - "Property 'message' does not exist on type 'never'. (2339)"
}
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WPZVeN)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Isn't it a little complicated?

Comment: The problem is that `"InvariantError" | "RequestError" | string` narrows to `string`. Just checking that `error.name` happens to be `"RequestError"` isn't enough for TypeScript to be able to say "ah, this is a `RequestError`", because that name is just as valid in the common interface which does not have a `response` property. If your intention was for the `ResponseError` to be exactly `InvariantError` or `RequestError`, then TypeScript is correct to error on the `else` because there should be no third option. tl;dr it's a little complicated for a good reason.